# boost::bind arguments of static function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I try to bind boost::asio arguments. Function to bind is static member of structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct bind_struct{

   typedef boost::system::error_code                         error_code;
   typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor                    tcp_acceptor_type;
   typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>     socket_type;


   static void tcp_on_async_accept(error_code& er,
                                  tcp_acceptor_type* acc,
                                  socket_type socket){
       std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
   }
   static void good_function(int m){
       std::cout << m << std::endl;
   }


};
```

Bind operation:

```
  /*Error*/
  bind_struct<void>::socket_type sock;
  bind_struct<void>::tcp_acceptor_type* acc;
  auto fn = boost::bind(bind_struct<void>::tcp_on_async_accept,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                acc, sock);
  fn();


  /*Ok*/
  auto fn1 = boost::bind(bind_struct<void>::good_function,_1);
  fn1(10);
```

What is a problem here? 
[Errors.](http://pastebin.com/Tfe8e53Y)

Comment: `bind()` may be confused since you're trying to bind a member function without an object on which to call it (which in theory is OK, since the member is static).  If you pass `&sock` as the second parameter to `bind()` does that change the errors?

Comment: @Chad smart_poiter by link it is normal?
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7615c6464bd2d488

Answer (score 2):

`fn()` fails because the functor expects the first argument passed to it to be able to bind to `boost::system::error_code&`.

The Boost.Asio documentation for [`boost::asio::placeholders::error`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/placeholders__error.html) states:

> An argument placeholder, for use with `boost::bind()`, that corresponds to the error argument of a handler for any of the asynchronous functions.

Hence, when the function:

```cpp
void bind_struct::tcp_on_async_accept(
    boost::system::error_code&,
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor*,
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>)
```

is bound with:

```cpp
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor* acceptor;
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket;
auto fn = boost::bind(
    bind_struct<void>::tcp_on_async_accept,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error, // _1
    acceptor, socket);
```

The resulting functor `fn` can only be invoked when the first argument passed to its invocation can bind to `boost::system::error_code&`.  Thus, the following will fail:

```cpp
fn();
```

where as the following will work:

```cpp
boost::system::error_code error;
fn(error);
```

Consider reading [this](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) blog for a great illustrated example of `bind()`.

---

If `bind_struct::tcp_on_async_accept()` is going to be used as the handler to an  [`async_accept()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html) operation, then consider changing the first parameter type to accept `error_code` by value or by const reference.  The [Asynchronous Operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) type requirements specifies that the first parameter for handlers is an lvalue of type `boost::system::error_code`, and the [AcceptHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html) documentation states if `h` is a handler and `ec` is a const `error_code`, then the expression `h(ec)` must be valid.  As a const `error_code` cannot be bound to `boost::system::error_code&`, `bind_struct::tcp_on_async_accept()` fails to meet the AcceptHandler type requirement.

Comment: I'll find an error. Function must receve just const boost::asio::error_code&. But it useful information.

Comment: @crastinus Per [AcceptHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html) documentation, if `h` is a handler and `ec` is a const `error_code`, then the expression `h(ec)` must be valid.  Hence, the function may accept `error_code` by value or by const reference.  When using `bind()`, addition arguments may be bound to the function when constructing the functor.  While `placeholders::error` (`_1`) may appear in the binding zero or multiple times, placeholders for different positions, such as `_2`, may not appear in the binding.